# Simple controller routing doesn't work in IIS for asp.net site hosted in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, iis, asp.net-web-api

Trying to host locally a rest service in IIS. Everything works fine in IIS Express but as soon as I try to host locally in IIS the routing doesn't work.

1. It's compiled to x86 and is hosted inside of an app pool that allows for 32 bit processes.
2. I have the site mapped to the binary output folder from my build `msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:ProcessorArchitecture=x86 -r:False`
3. I have `Anonymous Authentication` enabled
4. Binding is type `http` to port 8000
   [image]
5. I have enabled directory browsing and see the below at `http://localhost:8000/`
   [image]
6. However whenever I try to navigate to `http://localhost:8000/api/HeartBeat` I get a `404 - Not Found`.

My WebApiConfig class which sets a default route.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Here is the controller

```
public class HeartBeatController : ApiController
    {
        // GET: api/HearBeat/5
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }

    }
```

If I run this in IIS Express and navigate to that same url I get a 200. Also I've tried to examine the URL in powershell using `Get-WebUrl` and it shows a ProtocolError but I have no clue what or why. And IIS Manager doesn't seem to complain about anything.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WebURL -PSPath "IIS:\Sites\Test" | Format-list


Status      : ProtocolError
ResponseUri : http://localhost:8000/
Description : Forbidden
```

Comment: Have you installed the Windows Hosting Bundle and rebooted IIS? You're also going to want to disable directory browsing.

Comment: The `ProtocolError` indicates you don't have the IIS Management Service installed - or it's disabled - or blocked by your firewall.

Comment: Did you deploy a valid web.config file?

Comment: I will look at the Windows hosting bundle. I didn't realize there was another thing to turn on for IIS; and yes will disable directory browsing. This is on my dev machine and just trying to get something very simple working

Comment: Based on the directory browsing result, you map the wrong folder to the IIS site. Then 404 is expected. Before you know all details of ASP.NET deployment to IIS, please use VS publish wizard to publish binaries to file system and then map that output folder to the IIS site.

Comment: Please enable detailed errors mode in web.config and let us know the detailed error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things were amiss.

1. Publishing via Visual Studio is quite different than the build output that was created via the build command above.
2. I was missing under Windows features/IIS/Application Development Features
   [image: ![enter image description here]
3. Finally was still getting a security error which required adding an ACL rule to the directory